# SQL (MS ACCESS) Joining tables based on a maximum value

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am trying to join tables in MS ACCESS.
The tables in question are PatientDB and DailyAssessment.

The PatientDB table contains primary key Patient_UID.

The DailyAssessment table contains primary key Assessment_UID.
It also contains a Patient_UID field which is linked to PatientDB in the database relationships.

What I am trying to achieve is:

Select all records from PatientDB table that meet the criteria: Patient_Active = TRUE.

For each active record I want to retrieve the most recent entry in the DailyAssessments table.
So far I have tried to achieve this by using:

Max(Assessment_UID) As MaxOfAssessment_UID

Then using this value to attempt to JOIN a query that returns the other values in the DailyAssessment table.

The SQL appears as below:

```
SELECT PatientDB.Patient_UID, 
Max(DailyAssessment.Assessment_UID) AS 
MaxOfAssessment_UID, 
qryAssessmentData.Assessment_Date, 
qryAssessmentData.Assessment_Time, 
qryAssessmentData.Rescue_Analgesia, qryAssessmentData. 
[Review By], qryAssessmentData.Assessment_Grade, 
qryAssessmentData.Assessment_Notes
FROM (PatientDB INNER JOIN DailyAssessment ON 
PatientDB.Patient_UID = DailyAssessment.Patient_UID) 
INNER JOIN qryAssessmentData ON MaxOfAssessment_UID = 
qryAssessmentData.Assessment_UID
GROUP BY PatientDB.Patient_UID, 
qryAssessmentData.Assessment_Date, 
qryAssessmentData.Assessment_Time, 
qryAssessmentData.Rescue_Analgesia, qryAssessmentData. 
[Review By], qryAssessmentData.Assessment_Grade, 
qryAssessmentData.Assessment_Notes;
```

However I am getting a JOIN expression not supported error and it highlights the: 'JOIN qryAssessmentData ON MaxOfAssessment_UID = qryAssessmentData.Assessment_UID'.

Does anyone have any ideas how to achieve this - either a more simple method or am I just doing something wrong?  I have a fairly basic understanding of SQL so any suggestions appreciated!

Many thanks.

Comment: You say you have two tables, but your query references three.

Comment: It looks good but there are a few syntax errors in there that I can see. For example   I don't think the parenthesis around (FROM are necessary. Secondly, by the description of your problem I don't think you want to GROUP BY more than UID and the Date, as it will give you the outer product of those columns.

Comment: There are only two tables but the 3rd thing mentioned (qryAssessmentData) is a seperate query which simply returns all the data fields within the DailyAssessment table.  I did it this way to try and reduce the length of original SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a column alias a second time -- not in the `SELECT` nor `WHERE` nor `ON` (okay, you can in the `ORDER BY`).

You don't want aggregation anyway.  You simply want filtering.

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
SELECT . . .
FROM PatientDB as p INNER JOIN
     DailyAssessment as da
     ON p.Patient_UID = da.Patient_UID
WHERE da.Assessment_UID = (SELECT MAX(da2.Assessment_UID)
                           FROM DailyAssessment da2
                           WHERE da2.Patient_UID = da.Patient_UID
                          );
```

Notes:

- Your question gives no indication of what the third table is for.
- Your question gives no indication of how to determine if a patient is active.
- This introduces table aliases, so your query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: As above the third table, qryAssessmentData is just a query that returns all data from DailyAssessment table.  I use a WHERE PatientDB.Patient_Active = TRUE in a different version.  But I just wanted to get the filtering part for the maximum / most recent daily assessment data right first before filtering the active patients as that is already working elsewhere.  I appreciate the help Gordon.

Comment: I'm now finding that the queries return only the patient records that are active, and have an entry within the DailyAssessment table.  Can the query be modified to return all active patients even if they do not have an entry in DailyAssessments?